# Obtain the coordinates of one point (X1,Y1) where it is maximum the change of the curve

Tags: regression, exponential-distribution, extreme-value

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [biomedcentral.com](https://www.biomedcentral.com/content/figures/1471-2199-9-66-1-l.jpg))</sub>
Dear community,

I used a figure obtained from internet to illustrate what I would like to solve. Imagine this exponential regression curve.
How can I get the exact point of the curve where it is maximum the change of the it?
Observing the figure, it should be placed between 1 and 2 in the X axis and between 0.04 and 0.08 in the Y axis. But where it is exactly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maximum of the 2nd derivative?

Comment: If this is truly exponential, then the maximum of any odd-order derivative (such as its slope) is attained at 0 and the maximum of any even-order derivative is asymptotically reached at $\infty$: no calculation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute the second derivative = 0, which is called an "inflexion point".

To make things clear, let's take the Gauss curve as an example: the inflexion points are at $x = \pm\sigma$.

(Since the second derivative gives the concavity, an inflexion point is a point where the convexity of the curve changes.)

Comment: It is likely I did not write well what I wanted. In this figure there is only one concavity curve. Which is the point in that curve, I mean it's coordinates X and Y, where the curve is stronger? Here, there is not an inflexion point because there is not a change in the curve pattern (concavity-convexity or vice versa). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. Yes, you wrote correctly. I think that you should have a look at wikipedia article about inflection points, there's a video where you see the progress of the slope, explaining your issue.